# How to get count of WebElements using selenium webdriver in the following scenario:

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am dealing with some really odd html custom code and I am trying to get the count of elements present within a dynamic list. This list is not in a table format and it updates very often. Here is the xpath of the element that I need to get the count of:

```
leaf-data-object-list[@id='objectList']/iron-list[@id='dataObjectList']/div[@id='items']/leaf-data-object-list-row[1]
leaf-data-object-list[@id='objectList']/iron-list[@id='dataObjectList']/div[@id='items']/leaf-data-object-list-row[2]
```

Similarly there are more items in the list [3], [4] etc. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium You have FindElements() method which return List.
In Your case will be like

```
List<WebElement> link_boxes=driver.findElements(By.xpath("leaf-data-object-list[@id='objectList']/iron-list[@id='dataObjectList']/div[@id='items']"));
```

and that collection act like every other

Answer (score 0):

As per your code trials to get the count of elements present within the **dynamic list** you can induce *WebDriverWait* with *ExpectedConditions* as [**`visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as follows:

```
List<WebElement> myDynamicList = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//leaf-data-object-list[@id='objectList']/iron-list[@id='dataObjectList']/div[@id='items']/leaf-data-object-list-row")));
System.out.println("Number of elements are : " + myDynamicList.size());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and time! I ran the code however, it's not returning the exact count even though the list is populated entirely on the page.

Comment: @Velly As you mentioned `the list is populated entirely on the page` that is the reason why you don't see the **exact count**. You see the count of elements which are within the [**Viewport**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the information. This makes sense. Is there anyway for Selenium to handle this type of issue and get the entire count?

Comment: @Velly Of-coarse you can scroll down and collect all the nodes matching the _Locator Strategy_ and keep on appending to the _List_. You can raise a new ticket as per your new requirement. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.